# How to fix extra rendering of the page when accessing data from the Mobx store, after a request to the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux, mobx

I try in Mobx to make  "isLoggedIn" variable that will display whether the user is logged (true) in or not (false).

To do this, I need to make a request to the server in order to authenticate the user. The problem is that when I access the "isLoggedIn" variable, it is still undefined, since the request has not yet ended. It is filled after the server has given an answer. Because of this, my component is rendered twice.

The screenshot shows my problem.
[image]

What is the best way to organize this? I’ve been stuck with this logic for several days now, and I can’t understand how I should do it better.

I tried different options for working with API, but I just can’t solve the problem. To better understand the problem, I downloaded the sample code into the https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-85x7k

I want that when referring to "isLoggedIn" variable, that it contained data (true or false). I want to avoid extra page rendering.

Comment: Changing the observable variables always re-render the observer components. besides, MobX prevents component re-rendering if the old and new values of observables are shallowly equal.

Comment: I understand it
Apparently it’s impossible to make this function work in any other way